# Function for pow using only addition?

Tags: c++, pow

I have to make a function for pow, but cannot use multiplication. I know I have to make a function for multiplying then another function for finding the exponent. The function for multiplication works, but I'm having issues with the exponent function. Why isn't it multiplying as many times as the for loop?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int multiply(int, int);
int exponent(int, int);

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    cout << "Please enter a base number: ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Please enter another the exponent: ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Number: "<< exponent(a, b) << endl;

    return 0;
}


int multiply(int a, int b)
{
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
        x += a;
    return x;
}
int exponent(int a, int b)
{
    int y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
       y = multiply(a, a);
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your `int exponent(int a, int b)` to:

```
int exponent(int a, int b)
{
    int y = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
        y = multiply(y, a);
    return y;
}
```

**Key point 1**: Since you are multiplying things, the initial value should be `1`. You know, n*0=0 for all n.

**Key point 2**: To "accumulate" the multiplication, you need to use the "previous `y`" to get the "new `y`". It is the same idea as the `+=` operator in the `multiply` function, but it is a little bit tricky to think of since they looks differently.

*Minor point A*: We prefer pre-increment (`++i`) to post-increment (`i++`). In the near future, when you increment something not `int` (e.g. iterator), pre-increment has a little less overhead in case of your optimizer is not smart enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
 y = multiply(a, a);
```

Should be,

```
 y = multiply(y, a);
```

Also, as mentioned in comment, initilize y with 1.

```
y = 1
```

Comment: It will result in ba^2, not a^b

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind `exponent` is not right. You need to use:

```
int exponent(int a, int b)
{
   int y = 1;
   for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
      y = multiply(y, a);
   return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `exponent()` algorithm is wrong.  You have not implemented "x to the power of y", you have implemented "x multiplied by x, when y > 0" instead.

Try this:

```
int exponent(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return 1;
    int y = a;
    for (int i = 1; i < b; i++)
        y = multiply(y, a);
    return y;
}
```

In the future, you may or may not also need to handle negative powers (`b < 0`), so think about that.